# How should I cut cookie dough when in tube?

Tags: cookies

I have rolled my cookie dough (eggless recipe) into a tube and put into the fridge overnight (in clingfilm). When I come to cut it the next day, it crumbles half way through the cut. I have tried a thin knife, a serrated knife, even tried the floss method. I just end up with half the cookie intact and the other half in crumbs. What am I doing wrong to such a simple process?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice. Could you include the ingredient list (and quantities) in the question? That way it may be easier for someone to spot the problem

Comment: If you slice it, is it always the same part of the log that crumbles? In other words, if you turn the log/tube, is it always the part facing towards the board (or away) that crumbles?

Comment: It sounds a bit dry to me, you could try to add bit of water and see if it binds.

Comment: The ingredients are as follows: 500g butter, 500ml icing sugar, 675g flour, 10ml baking powder and a pinch of salt.With regard to the crumbling, even if we turn the "tube" it crumbles almost half way down to the board, so yes it is always the same part that crumbles.  When working with the dough it is not at all crumbly, but will try anything at this point. thank you for the feedback

Comment: There is no liquid at all in you formula?  (except whats in the butter.) Seems it would be very dry and crumbly.  Did you take a formula and omit the eggs, or is it formulated this way on purpose.  where did this formula come from, can post the source.

Comment: What would be the OPs preferred solution, a dough that is more robust when cutting, or advice on cutting technique?

Comment: well, I would assume it would be cutting technique or it could be the dough.  Once baked it is a nice biscuit, just cant cut a perfect round, half the circle crumbles when cutting.  so am not sure if it is the technique or the dough.

Comment: @TDConfectionery You use the word biscuit in your comment but cookie in your question.  Biscuits are rolled out like pie dough and cut with a biscuit or cookie cutter and then placed on a sheet pan with a spatula. Cookie or Biscuit ???

Comment: Have you already tried greasing the thin knife?

Comment: thank you, yes tried greasing our thin knife. even tried a cold knife.  still no clean cut.  but thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you say you have tree the dental floss method, how did you hold the floss? I have had really good results by putting the floss under the roll of the dough and crossing the tails over the top of the roll and pulling the tails until the dough disc is cut off the roll. That way there is no downward pressure to crumble the sides of the roll.

Comment: right will give that one a bash and get back to you.  thank you